# .htaccess problems with redirection

Tags: php, htaccess, redirects, mod-rewrite

I apologize ahead of time that this might be a common question, however I've spent 3-4 hours already on solutions which don't quite fix the problem.

I have a site and it is moving to a different domain, the problem is--the site is paired with software which looks for: `http://site/version`. Using a simple 301 redirect won't work because it'll get '301 Moved Permanently' instead of the actual data. So I thought.. ok--I made `version.php` which has:

```
<? echo file_get_contents('http://newsite/version'); ?>
```

So the idea is simple: When one requests `http://site/version`, give them `http://site/version.php`, else: redirect everything to `http://newsite/$1`

What I got was something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/version$ /version.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^version$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [R=301]
```

I am no master at mod_rewrite rules, this is just what I hacked together and it doesn't work or I wouldn't be here. If someone who knows them better than I can help, I'd be very grateful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I assume both `site` and `newsite` are hosted at the same place - one is a _parked_ domain on the other?

Comment: that is not the case, they are completely different locations.

Comment: In that case (unless there are other hosts/domains involved) then you don't need to check against `%{HTTP_HOST}`, since it will _always_ be `site.com`, and these `RewriteCond` directives can be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the correct idea, but the directory prefix (`/`) is probably the main thing that is causing problems. Try the following...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^version$ /version.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/version
RewriteRule (.*) http://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* in per-directory .htaccess files is matched against the URL less the directory prefix (ie. `version`, not `/version`), so your pattern would never match.

Conversely the `REQUEST_URI` variable always includes the full URI, including the directory prefix (`/`). And in this case, it is likely to be the rewritten URL, ie. `/version.php` and not `/version`. Although I simply removed the end-of-string placeholder (`$`) so it will catch both anyway - assuming you don't have other URLs that start "/version"?

**EDIT:** Note that if `site.com` and `newsite.com` are completely separate sites (as suggested in comments) and no other domains are parked at `site.com` then you don't need to check the `%{HTTP_HOST}` and these `RewriteCond` directives can be removed.

Comment: This worked out perfectly. Thank you very much for your help as well as your explanation. I do not have any other url's prefixed with version but if that does happen I can simply do `^version(|.php)$`

Comment: Yes, although it is probably preferable to write that as `^/version(\.php)?$` to make the ".php" optional and remember to escape the `.` in the regex. To be honest, I'm pretty sure you can just replace this with `^/version\.php$` (the rewritten URL), providing your directives remain in the same order as above.